# Не отображается UserControl в конструкторе WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, usercontrol

Cуть проблемы в том что у меня есть три usercontrol-а для трех фигур, два из них отображаются, а один нет(обведен красным, в контроле должно быть видно три текстбокса). Не отображается ни в конструкторе форм, ни при выполнении программы. Пробовал уже все, исключать из проекта добавлять заново, пересобирать, очищать, удалял контрол полностью и кидал по новой. Уже не знаю что делать, перерыл практически всё, даже англоязычные форумы. В коде описан он ровно так же как и два других, которые отображаются.

Спасибо за ответ!

[image]

Comment: С виду у вас довольно простой проект. Если есть возможность, выложите где-нибудь файлы формы и проблемного юзер контрола (вместе  с  Designer.cs). Или попробуйте сделать совсем простой проект с аналогичной проблемой и выложите (например на GitHub).

Comment: Попробуйте сначала сделать этому юзер контролу на форме [BringToFront](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront(v=vs.110).aspx). Возможно, он перекрывается другим контролом.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но решение абсолютно тупейшее получилось. Я просто  public ParallelepipedControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
         вот эти строчки забыл написать, а к другим двум контролам не забыл! Еще раз спасибо за потраченное время, я просто невнимательный дурачок оказался!))